# Why doesn't the family live next to the waterfall?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place

In such a horrible condition for living as in *The Quiet Place*, I'm not sure why the family didn't leave the house where they had to tip toe all the time and live under a constant fear of not making a sound and simply **build a hut near the waterfall** where there was constant noise covering their sounds.

Or they could replicate the noise of the waterfall by having some loud speakers around the house constantly giving out a white noise.

Comment: "loud speakers around the house constantly giving out a white noise" would mean that any monster passing by the area would take a detour to investigate the noisy house. Attaching a monster-attracting beacon to your house doesn't seem smart. We've seen what they do when they find no food but no obvious explanation for the noise - they search, entering buildings, climbing stairs... The dad's whiteboard tells us they don't know how many monsters are out there - just that they've observed three. They don't want more.

Comment: @user568458, comments are not a place for an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure we know precisely where the movie is set; but my **second** thought after 'why not live by the waterfall?' was 'why not live by the sea?' Plenty of houses there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a fair point, but I have to ask: Did you see any vacant houses there? I didn't, and I certainly wouldn't go about the noisy task of building a structure from scratch. Transporting materials would be a nightmare.

Moreover Evelyn was pregnant, you cannot live in a hut with a pregnant woman, a physically disabled child and a kid who is a shivering wreck.

They can't possibly afford to constantly run speakers because it would consume lot of electricity.We still aren't sure of the source of Electricity(There are a lot of theories like [solar energy](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/8a5qdo/official_discussion_a_quiet_place_spoilers/dx3c5w2/) & [batteries](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/8aiw9h/spoiler_a_quiet_place_plot_hole_discussion_and/dx2puzt/))

Comment: Evelyn was pregnant YEAR after first scene. And the creatures was on earth much earlier. and you don't need waterfall to make constant  noise. Also the problem is why creatures attack humans when everything on earth make some noise.

Comment: Nowhere does it say the creatures attack only humans,It may have been attacking animals as well

Comment: I meant things that make noise. Trees, said waterfalls, houses settling down, burning Gates to Hell, clocks.

Comment: They do attack clocks, we saw a character using a loud clock as a decoy. And they do attack animals, we saw them eat a racoon and heard them attack some birds. Presumably the first time they heard the waterfall, they investigated it, found no food, and learned to ignore that particular sound.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the family could build reasonable living quarters near the waterfall, and could obtain enough food there, there's another problem.

On the farm, normality means being as quiet as possible.  Being at the waterfall is a rare exception to that, where they can make as much noise as they like.

If they lived near the waterfall, normality would mean making as much noise as they like, and venturing outside the waterfall zone would require silence.

How much success would they have in impressing upon the children the need for silence if their normal home life allowed any amount of noise?  The parents are in it for the long haul; they're trying to raise a family and survive long-term, not just hold out for some vague rescue in the future.  So constant silence is something their kids need to learn, and something they wouldn't learn living by the waterfall.